# Просуммировать значения в массиве объектов

Tags: php

Дан массив $animals вида

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(Chicken)#2 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["egg"]=>
    int(0)
    ["typeProduct"]=>
    string(8) "Яица"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(Cow)#3 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["milk"]=>
    int(10)
    ["typeProduct"]=>
    string(12) "Молоко"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(Chicken)#4 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["egg"]=>
    int(0)
    ["typeProduct"]=>
    string(8) "Яица"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(Cow)#5 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(4)
    ["milk"]=>
    int(9)
    ["typeProduct"]=>
    string(12) "Молоко"
  }
```

Нужно преобразовать его так, чтобы он подсчитывал кол-во продукта.

Пример

```
array('Молоко' => 19, 'Яица' => 0)
```

Comment: приведите код, который вы уже написали для решения данной задачи

Comment: foreach ($animals as $animal) {
 $products[] = [$animal->typeProduct => $animal->getProduct()];
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используем функцию [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php)

```
$result = array_reduce(
    $data,
    function($acc, $el) {
        // преобразуем объект в массив
        $el = (array)$el;

        if (!isset($acc[$el['typeProduct']])) $acc[$el['typeProduct']] = 0;

        $acc[$el['typeProduct']] += $el[array_keys($el)[1]];
        return $acc;
    },
    []
);
```

[Execute PHP online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=88d78a5fecf20cb4e0e0c66532465337&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: а зачем преобразовать объект в массив?

Comment: @teran, Что бы получить количество не зная имя ключа, по его номеру

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev, `$var instanceof Cow`